# What is the species name of this moth?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

This insect was found in India. It looks like a **hawk moth** to me, but I still can't get the exact name for this species.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it is the vine hawk moth (Choerocampa rosetta).

[image]

https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2010/11/20/vine-hawk-moth/

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It would be highly appreciated if you add some more details and some images for comparison. Link-only answers are generally not welcomed since links can get invalid if they break or the link address changes.

Comment: I would be happy to. Is there a way to copy/paste pictures into the answer or can I only do it through "upload"?

Comment: You can paste a link to the image. Just above the answer-editing box, there is an image button. When you click on it, you will get options to both upload an image as well as paste a link for it. If the site refuses the image format, you will need to upload it.